# WIndows - Check my user account has install privileges before install

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-installer

I am in the process of creating a script a user would run on their local machine to install an application by running msiexec. Unfortunately the install will fail if the user does not have to correct privileges.

msiexec does write to a log and will tell me that it's failed due to permissions but I do not find this to be a very elegant solution.

How can I find out locally from a Windows command line whether or not they can install applications?

Comment: You mean Administrative Privileges?

Comment: Perhaps, I know administrator can install, what I don't know is if others can with certain permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that there are policy settings which can allow a non admin user to run an msi, so you may need to incorporate that with an admin check just in case they are set.

```bat
@Echo Off
"%__APPDIR__%net.exe" Session >Nul 2>&1 && GoTo Success
Set "RKey=HKCU HKLM"
Set "SKey=SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer"
Set "KVal=AlwaysInstallElevated"
Set "KDat=0"
For %%A In (%RKey%) Do For /F "Tokens=3" %%B In (
    '"%__APPDIR__%reg.exe" Query "%%A\%SKey%" /V "%KVal%" 2^>Nul'
) Do Set/A KDat+=%%B
If %KDat% NEq 2 Exit/B

:Success
Echo( You can install!
Timeout -1
```

*Just change the code below `:Success` to run your .msi installer.*